# Problem with scanf and fgets

Tags: c, stdin, scanf, fgets

This is for a homework assignment to sort some given strings. I'm prompting the user for the number of strings they'd like to sort with `scanf`, allocating an array based on that number, and then getting the strings themselves with `fgets`.

Everything works fine if the number of strings is hardcoded, but the addition of `scanf` to let the user decide screws things up. Here's the code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH  20 // Maximum string length.

int main(void)
{
    int index, numStrings = 0;
    char **stringArray;
    printf("Input the number of strings that you'd like to sort: ");
    assert(scanf("%d", &numStrings) == 1);
    stringArray = (char **)malloc(numStrings * sizeof(char *));

    for (index = 0; index < numStrings; index++)
    {
        stringArray[index] = (char *)malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(char));
        assert(stringArray[index] != NULL);
        printf("Input string: ");
        assert(fgets(stringArray[index], LENGTH, stdin) != NULL);
    }

    // Sort strings, free allocated memory.

    return 0;
}
```

And here's what the console looks like:

```
Input the number of strings that you'd like to sort: 3
Input string: Input string: foo
Input string: bar
```

It skips over the first iteration of the loop, resulting in an empty string at the beginning of the array. My question is, why does it do that, and how can I fix it?

---

Here's what the console looks with the format string `"%d\n"` passed to `scanf`:

```
Input the number of strings that you'd like to sort: 3
foo
Input string: Input string: bar
Input string: baz
```

So, I can input all of the strings, but the first prompt for a string is in the wrong place.

Comment: Don't `assert()` on functions that can reasonably be expected to fail, such as input functions that read user input.  It is better than ignoring the error; it is not as good as handling the error sanely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real answer (in my humble but ever-so-correct opinion :P) is not to use `scanf`. Use `fgets` to read the first line (i.e. the number) and then parse that string yourself with, say, `sscanf` or `strtoul`. That way you have the ability to handle errors when someone doesn't input the data in a nice format, and you don't have to hack around `scanf`'s lack of robust whitespace handling.

Also, never used an `int` to store sizes unless you expect to have a lot of arrays with -4 length. The standard specifies the unsigned type `size_t` as an unsigned type that is large enough to store object sizes and array indices. Using any other type isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: What part of my code are you referring to when you say not to use an int to store sizes?

Comment: @Charlatan - `numberOfStrings` specifically, and really anything you pass to `malloc`, receive from `strlen` or use to index an array should be a `size_t`.

Comment: So, how do you recommend that I get something of type `size_t` to pass to `malloc` from `stdin`? Parse an int and cast it? I went with your answer, by the way (used `atoi`), and it works fine now.

Comment: @Charlatan - You may be overthinking a bit. ;) `size_t` is a typedef to an unsigned integral type. Just use it in place of an `int`, like in `size_t len = 0;` (Helpful tip: the format to print a `size_t` is `"%zu"`. You can use another format that takes an unsigned type (like `"x"`) in place of the `"u"`.)

Comment: While you usually should use a size_t for store sizes as you suggest, note that the function you recommend he uses, fgets, takes an int for it's size,  not a size_t (and that fputs returns an int, not a size_t): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: @Zach - `fputs` is understandable, since it returns `EOF` on failure. `fgets` taking an `int` is probably done either for symmetry (which IMHO was a bad idea) or legacy (which may also be a bad idea). Interestingly, the standard (and all the documentation I've found on it) says nothing about the possibility of `fgets` being given a negative argument, so I think this may be an error. I imagine on most systems that it will end up being cast to an unsigned integral type.

Answer (score 6):

You have to tell scanf to clobber the \n by putting \n in the scanf:

```
scanf("%d\n", &numStrings)
```

without it, scanf will read the residual newline character [from when the enter button was hit] as the first line in the loop

Comment: A couple more comments to add to Foo Bah's answer:  One issue in your code is that you should not do anything with side effects inside `assert`; things inside `assert` are not run in release mode.  You might also want to put `fflush(stdout);` after your `printf` to make sure the prompt is printed before the user is asked for input.

Comment: also note that fgets will include the terminating newline character if your string is not too long

Comment: And, if the string is too long, then `fgets()` will leave the remaining characters of the line to be read by the next call to one of the standard I/O functions.

Comment: Adding `\n` lets me input all of the strings, but the first `Input string:` prompt is still in the wrong place. Shows up after I input the string, on the same line as the next prompt. See the edit on my question.